# RESTful service response code for Partially valid payload

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes, nancy

I have a RESTFul service with 2 query parameters, say `paramOne` & `Paramtwo`
The possible URLs would be

> `http://someApi/someResource?paramone=1&paramtwo=2`
>    `http://someApi/someResource?paramone=1`
>    `http://someApi/someResource?paramtwo=2`

The relation between `paramOne` & `Paramtwo` is one to many. So, with second route the result would contain a collection of objects. Now, if parameters we send are invalid, then the service would return `400 BAD REQUEST`.
Here comes my question. If a user requests by giving one valid and other invalid param like `http://someApi/someResource?paramone=1&paramtwo=invalidData` then what woould be the HTTP status code? Is it a `BAD REQUEST`? Or a collection of objects based on `paramone`? (As paramone is valid)

From the [Robustness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): "Be conservative in what you do [send], be liberal in what you accept.", I would expect a collection and neglect the invalid `Paramtwo`. And, when it comes to `DELETE` operation, this deletes all the objects with `paramone`. So is it OK to have this or it should be badrequest?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REST an URI should be treated as an atomic identifier, including the querystring. In theory, that means you should return `404 Not Found`, even though the base resource to which the querystring is applied exists. However, I believe most APIs are more pragmatic about that and tend to return `400 Bad Request` on invalid querystring parameters, based on the principle of least astonishment. If that's adopted consistently, fine.

I believe it's better to reject the whole request with a clear indication of the error and expect the user to correct it, than giving a partial success where the user might overlook the error. If you want the request to succeed partially, HTTP has no standard for that, but you may adopt the `207 Multi-Status` WebDav response if you want.